# Rule in htaccess file

Tags: mod-rewrite

Somebody could help me for this php rule "RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$" what's that mean?

I did this :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.html?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. There is no connection between rewrite rules and php. But apart from that: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

That pattern means match the entire string, the `(?s)` is an internal option setting to ensure that `.` also matches line break characters, which is not necessary.